# Limit superior, sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can anyone tell me how to find limit superior of $\{(-1)^n/2^n : n = 1, 2, ... \}$

I separated the sequences and my answer is coming out to be 1/3. But options are
$$ 1 \\
0\\
-1 \\
1/4 $$

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: try to include as much info you can especially your own working. It is hard to find out what is wrong with your working otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

The sequence converges, when a sequence converges, you just have to find its limit and it is equal to the limit superior.